Noun + adjective order in everyday English and poetry ("By the rivers dark")
I know that in English, most of the time, we have this order: adjective + noun, example:

a beautiful painting


cold rivers (plural)

Today I heard the Leonard Cohen song:

By the rivers dark
I wandered on
I lived my life
In Babylon

and it's one of the first time I hear this order noun + adjective (this would be the usual order in French).
How common is this in everyday English? Would you have examples?
Also, how common is this in poetry/songs, again would you have examples?
Note: this is linked to Can you put an adjective after a noun? and When can an adjective be postposed? but here it's more focused on poetry.

Related on ELL: Can you put an adjective after a noun?

Far over the misty mountains cold / to dungeons deep and caverns old / we may transpose our standard prose / and, bonus, make it feel "Ye-Olde."

It's uncommon in everyday English except for a few set expressions like court martial, secretary general.  More common in poetry, such as the verse Andy is parodying - https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Far_over_the_misty_mountains_cold

There is a small group of adjectives that that are generally only postposed, such as aplenty, elect, and galore, and a few we took from the French, like extraordinaire and manqué.

Thanks everyone for your comments (that could become answers which I will happily upvote!). I think here it's a bit different than the other linked questions, because of the focus on poetry vs. everyday use.

We sail the ocean blue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7rbVZS1Pvk
